# Is there any to access model parameter with partial view returned from AJAX?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So I have an AJAX method which is used to refresh the screen. I send parameters to a controller and it returns a partial view. Is there any way to access the model parameters when the partial view is returned?

AJAX code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnSave", function (e) {

            var studentId = $('#StudentId').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Student/InsertNew/",
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    studentId : studentId 
                },
                cache: true,
                async: true,
            }).done(function (result) {                    
                $("#divStudentTable").html(result);
                if(result.IsStudent){
                   //How do I get the studentId value returned from the controller?
                }  
            }
    })
```

Controller :

```
public ActionResult InsertNew(string studentId )
{
   .
   .
   .
   .
   .
   return PartialView("_StudentListPartial", model);

}
```

Model :

```
public class RegisterRegistrantViewModel
{
    public string StudentId { get; set; }
    public bool IsStudent { get; set; }
}
```

So is there a way I can access IsStudent from the AJAX success??

Comment: You will need to place it into your partial view somewhere, perhaps in a <input type='hidden'> then query for that in the resulting html. Alternatively, consider sending JSON back instead of a partial and build the HTML in your handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place it in an element and query that, for example in your partial:

```
<input type="hidden" id="isStudentHidden" value="@Model.IsStudent" />
```

Then in your done handler:

```
var isStudent = $("body").find("#isStudentHidden").val();
```

Comment: The issue though is it doesn't seem to change the value of the hidden field after refresh immediately in AJAX done handler. It still retains the old value and only changes after the AJAX function is complete.

Comment: The done handler should only run after the ajax function is complete....